# Why scroll in windows forms always jumps to selected item?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have listView in windows forms. 
View is Tile and Alignment is SnapToGrid and TileSize is 750;15. 
I also have function which deletes first element when list reach 60 elements.

```
while (listView3.Items.Count > 60) {
                listView3.Items.Remove(listView3.Items[0]);
            }
```

But vertical Scroll is always jumps to selected item. How could I solve it?

Comment: Use the TopItem property to control the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in that scroll jumped to selected item and item was selected on start so I didn't knew about that. I just used

```
listView3.FocusedItem.Focused = false;
```

and it worked